# how to draw the scan range in the gantry tilt cases?

Tags: image, dicom, image-scanner, medical

The **scan/recon range** rectangles on the **Topo/Scout image** show the scan/recon ranges for next scans/recons. The **width** of the rectangle represents the **FOV** and the **height** represents the **scan/recon length**. FOV here will be scan FOV for scan range or recon FOV for recon range.

In the case of **gantry tilt**, the rectangles are replaced with **parallelograms**. I am wondering what is **FOV** and what is **scan/recon length** then?

Is the **FOV** still showed as the **width** of the parallelograms? or the **length** of the top/bottom line is the **FOV** now?

Is the **height** of the parallelograms still the **scan/recon length**?

how to determine the parallelograms will **slope to right or left**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the best method to approach this is to use David Clunie's localizer line method for your top and bottom slice (section 2.2.1 of http://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part2.html).

Once you have the top and bottom line, just connect the ends to each other to complete your parallelogram.